# Parameterizing strings in a model not working

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to parameterize a string and set that string as the result of a model:

SomePanel.java

```
public SomePanel( String id, IModel<Person> personModel)
{
  tallLabel = new Label( "height", new LoadableDetachableModel() {
    pubic String load() {
      Person person = personModel.getObject();
      boolean isTall = apiCallToCheckIfTall( person );

      // 'name' is a property on PersonModel
      String name = person.getName();

      String tallString = MessageFormat.format(getString("Tall.Label"), name );
      String shortString = MessageFormat.format(getString("Short.Label"), name );
  
      return isTall ? tallString : shortString;
    }
  });

  add(tallLabel);
}
```

Text.properties

```
Tall.Label = ${name} is tall.
Short.Label = ${name} is short.
```

I tried implementing a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976888/simple-way-to-use-parameterised-ui-messages-in-wicket) but `contact.getName()` produces an error. My understanding is that `personModel.getObject()` would give me the actual object (which has getter `getName` defined) so not sure why this would produce an error.

Comment: What exactly is the error ? What are `TallModel` and `ShortModel` ? They are not defined earlier and look like classes with static methods.

Comment: @martin-g I revised the question. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

MessageFormat uses indexed parameters, so you probably mixed up some technologies here.

Here's the simplest solution using Wicket's resource messages with names parameters:

```
return getString(isTall ? "Tall.Label" : "Short.Label", personModel)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. When the dropdown (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452003/api-call-not-triggered-in-onchange-of-dropdown-selection) is unselected; however, `$name` shows in the displayed text (`${name} is tall`). Am I supposed to be handling this case?

Comment: Well, without a selection the person is null. I don't know what you want to display in that case, e.g. you could override #onConfigure and #setVisible(false).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with:

SomePanel.java

```
public SomePanel( String id, IModel<Person> personModel)
{
  tallLabel = new Label( "height", new LoadableDetachableModel() {
    public String load() {
      Person person = personModel.getObject();
      boolean isTall = apiCallToCheckIfTall( person );

      PersonGetter getter = new PersonGetter ( personModel );
      String name = getter.getName();

      String RTStringModel = MessageFormat.format( getString("Tall.Label"), person.getName() );
      String StringModel = MessageFormat.format( getString("Short.Label"), person.getName() );
  
      return isTall ? RTStringModel : StringModel;
    }
  });

  add(tallLabel);
}

...

private class NameGetter implements Serializable
{
    private final IModel<Person> model;

    public NameGetter( final IModel<Person> personModel )
    {
        this.model = person;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return getFormattedLegalName( this.model.getObject() );
    }
}

public static final String getFormattedLegalName( Person person )
{
    if ( person == null )
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return person.getName();
    }
}
```

Text.properties

```
Tall.Label = {0} is tall.
Short.Label = {0} is short.
```

This seems to be a bit too much to extract a value from the model though. I couldn't get the name from the `personModel` directly (e.g. `personModel.getObject().getName()`) and went the convoluted route of having to create another class.